# Interpreting "elliptic" shape in visualization of high-dimensional dataset, e.g. COIL-20?

Tags: data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction

There exist an image dataset referred to as [COIL-20](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/publications/pdfs/Nene_TR96.pdf). There are several paper that describes different dimensionality reduction methods and apply them to produce a 2d plot of this dataset. These pictures often contain one or several "elliptic" shapes. Is there any particular explanation for this? If yes, can we extend it to other datasets? E.g. if we observe the similar"elliptic" shapes on completely different dataset (not images), is it possible to infer something about its structure?

For example, the picture by [t-SNE](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf):

[image]

or from [here](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~elgammal/pub/ICPR10_multimanifold.pdf):

[image]

and [here](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~bredeweg/pdf/BSc/20082009/Formsma.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The COIL-20 dataset contains many pictures of the same object, taken from different angles. Suppose the angle is denoted by $t \in [0,2\pi)$, and we should really think of $[0,2\pi)$ as the circle $\mathbb{S}$. If the sample images are taken for a sufficiently dense and uniform set of $t \in \mathbb{S}$, then the algorithm detects this copy of $\mathbb{S}$ lurking in the data and a deformed ellipse appears. In other words, the algorithm is implicitly parameterizing the dataset: for the subset of images corresponding to one particular object, this subset may be parameterized by the single parameter $t \in \mathbb{S}$.

There is a nice discussion about this phenomenon on p.35-43 of S. Lafon's thesis. Lafon is discussing diffusion mapping, and using the UMIST dataset as an example, but the notion of dataset parameterization is the same. There is a very nice 2-parameter example in the figure on p.43.